# How to restrict Java Web Start to run only a set of known .jnlp files?

Tags: java, jnlp, java-web-start

Is there a way to restrict the .jnlp files Web Start is allowed to load to a known set of URLs?

Company policy prohibits users to install any software and Java Web Start has been flagged because it allows users to "install" and run applications via .jnlp files.

Comment: Is there a company wide way to restrict access to certain file types at firewall level? If yes, then you (or administrator) can restrict all urls ending jnlp and allow only a limited set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup a firewall and then you (or administrator) can restrict all urls ending jnlp and allow only a limited set.

Comment: Yup! I was thinking to work this out with the proxy folks but I'm rather baffled there's nothing in the application that would facilitate this =(

Comment: You do understand that the usual flow of accessing web start applications is through browsers. Just like browser calls pdf viewer when it encounters proper mime type for pdf, it calls javaws when it encounters jnlp. Of course, you call use javaws to directly call jnlp content as well, just like any other networked application on your system.